# Ubuntu 16.04 "upgrade" wiped out existing 15.10 installation

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I've had some big problems with my Ubuntu upgrading from 14.04 (got stuck for some reason on a failed 15.10).  To solve, I made an Ubuntu 16.04 live USB to reinstall.  When I booted to the USB and selected the Installation option, I selected the first option to Upgrade 15.10 to 16.04.  During the installation it asked for my computer's name and also my username.

After the installation, I appear to have a completely fresh 16.04 installation, despite my instructions.

Do I have any hope of recovering my existing overwritten setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, that's [bug 1265192](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192), "Install/reinstall wipes out all other partitions".  You can add yourself to the "does this bug affect me" list by clicking on the yellow icon next to the question.

Comment: Adding a link to this bug report on Launchpad would be nice.

Comment: How TF does "Upgrade" get misunderstood as wipe and install.  That is completely ridiculous.  Oh, and to make matters worse, a fix has *not* been released as the bug report said.